# How to dynamically move HTML 5 range input handle without using Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

**WHAT:**

I have an HTML5 range input slider. If I use jQuery to change the value of said slider, the handle's position does not change.  This can be achieved using the .slider() method in the jQuery UI framework. However, I want to achieve the same result using the jQuery library.

**QUESTION:**

How do I dynamically set the value of an HTML 5 range input and have the handle move position using jQuery 1.11.2 or Javascript.

**CODE ATTEMPTS:**

Below is 2 snippets of code  that I've used to try solve the problem.

```
$("#rangeInput").attr("value", "100");

$("#rangeInput").val("100")
```

**THE FORM:**

```
    <form id="noisePolForm">
<input id="rangeInput" type="range" value="0" step="3" min="80" max="140" class="noisePol">
    </form>
```

Comment: Note the second one should be `$("#rangeInput").val("100")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `.prop()`, not `.attr()`:

```
$("#rangeInput").prop("value", "100"); //Or $("#rangeInput").prop("value", 100);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qy2a43yu/)**

Your second example works fine, you just forgot the `#`

```
$("#rangeInput").val("100") //Or $("#rangeInput").val(100)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vjkrrmz9/)**

Comment: The OPs code works in older version of jQuery. Note this is because *"As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values while .attr() retrieves attributes."*.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - after jQuery 1.6 .prop() supplanted .attr() for most of what attr() was being used for.

Comment: Great to know to use .prop() instead of .attr() now. Thanks!